# Can't add tags from .vh file as systemverilog file

Tags: system-verilog, ctags

Trying to generate tags for some system verilog files, I found some file's the file extension was just .vh. And my 'ctags --list-maps' showed only *.sv, *.svh and *.svi is identified as systemverilog files.
Not waning to change file names, I changed in my ~/.ctags file,

```
--langmap=systemverilog:.sv.svh.svi
```

to

```
--langmap=systemverilog:.sv.svh.svi.vh
```

But still, the .vh file's content is not updated in the tags file. My ctags version is below.

```
Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex
```

and I tried with universal-ctags but it was the same.  How can I add .vh file in the systemverilog list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found by overriding the verilog extension, I can include .vh files. This is how I did it.

```
ctags --langmap=verilog:.v.vh -R *
```

And I added `--langmap=verilog:.v.vh` in ~/.ctags, then `ctags -R *` also works without giving the option in the command line.
This I tried this with exuberant-ctags but I guess it'll be the same with universal-ctags.